# Git - How to keep cloned repository updated

Tags: git, github, merge

I cloned a repository using the tutorial on [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository). I regularly change things in the cloned repository. From time to time I want to merge the changes from the original repository.

This works, but I have to merge things that I merged some time ago again. So you can see that the left and right side are identical, but the merged version contains an old version that was there when originally cloning the repository.

How to keep the cloned repository up to date with the original repository without merging changes over and over again, every time something changes in the file.

I will add a small example:

At one point the original repository changes method a() of Class C to b() and I merge that change.
If in the future something else in Class C changes, I see that my local version contains method b() and the remote version contains method b(), but the merged version contains method a().

Answer (score 1):

- After cloning a repository, create a new branch for working .
- On that new branch, do your work and commit.
- When original updates, checkout master and pull.
- Merge your new branch with master.
- Create another new branch for continue working with new version of original cloned.

So you have to merge only one time when original update !

Comment: But then I have to create a new branch every time? I want to work on my master branch as well.

Comment: "... branches are cheap to create and destroy ..." branch in Git is killer feature to get rid of other problems. So you can create and delete after merging branches to master. it is not problem with your old commits. Why do you want to work in master ? create new branch and working on it and marge to master is better choice for many situation. Because sometime you also want create some branch for test some features only.